# How to add a custom code that will be displayed in the header for visitors who come from a specific promotion

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to add a custom code (e.g. save 15% with the code: 15OFF) that will be displayed in the header, for visitors who come from a specific promotion, (link e.g. example.com?promo) and the custom code should remain displayed on all pages that the visitors will visit

```html
        <div style="display:table;height: 40px;background-color: #f8f8f8;padding: 1px;line-height: 1.3;width: 100%;">
            <div style="display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">
                <div style="color: #000;text-align: center;font-size: 13px;">Save 15% off with code 15OFF</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your idea is to give users that should see the banner a specific url, you could put there something like a get parameter and search for it using javascript. Please note that this is ok if your server is ignoring the get parameter.

You can modify your div to be normally hidden

```
 <div style="display:none; height: 40px; background-color: #f8f8f8; padding: 1px; line-height: 1.3; width: 100%;">
    <div style="display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">
       <div style="color: #000;text-align: center;font-size: 13px;">
           Save 15% off with code 15OFF
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

and check if there is a get parameter called *promo* set to *true*; in that case, make your div visible.

```
  var url = new URL(window.location.href);
    var promo = url.searchParams.get("promo");
    if(promo == 'true'){
       document.getElementById("promoBanner").style.display = "table";
  }
```

Please note that with this solution, if you want to show the same banner in the next pages visited, you have to keep the get information, so links should be properly handled (for example)

```
<a onclick="window.location='newPageLink'+window.location.search;">
   Link
</a>
```

Comment: The script didn't work for me, I used this instead: if(window.location.href.indexOf("promo") > -1) { $("#promo").show(); } 
The onclick worked well for me thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you'll need to answer is, "How does the browser know that they came from a specific promotion?" In a lot of cases, your promotion link will have a specific URL parameter which can inform the browser where they came from.

```
const queryString = window.location.search.substring(1);
const params = queryString.split('&')
params = params.map(param => {
    param = param.split('=');
    return {
        name: param[0], 
        value: param[1]
    }
})

if ( params.includes({name: 'fromPromo', value: 'true'}) ) {
    // create an element and push it to your page
}
```

All this said, this kind of task is much more easily handled with a front-end framework like React, Angular, Vue, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Toggle it using `document.referer` perhaps.

```js
const fromHere = ["wwww.example.com", "www.example.org"];

var toggleState = function(elem, fromMe) {
  var elem = document.querySelector(elem);
  elem.setAttribute('data-state', fromHere.includes(fromMe) ? "hidden" : "shown");
};
const hiddenGem = '.only-if-from';
let fromMe = document.referer;
fromMe = "www.example.com"; // fake for test
toggleState(hiddenGem, fromMe);
```

```css
.only-if-from[data-state=hidden] {
  display: none;
}

.only-if-from[data-state=shown] {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="only-if-from" data-state="hidden">
  <div style="display:table;height: 40px;background-color: #f8f8f8;padding: 1px;line-height: 1.3;width: 100%;">
    <div style="display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">
      <div style="color: #000;text-align: center;font-size: 13px;">Save 15% off with code 15OFF</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```